How to use moti animation in a big list and maintain smooth performance
I'm working on a React Native project where I need to render a large list of items using FlatList. Each item in the list includes some animations powered by the MotiView component from the moti library. The animations are smooth, but as the list grows, performance starts to degrade, especially on lower-end devices.
Here’s a simplified version of my code:
import React from "react";
import { FlatList, View, Text } from "react-native";
import { MotiView } from "moti";

const _stagger = 50;
const numbersToNice = [...Array(10).keys()];

// This component renders each animated number list
function TickerList({ number, fontSize, index }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ height: fontSize, overflow: "hidden" }}>
      <MotiView
        animate={{ translateY: -fontSize * 1.11 * number }}
        transition={{ delay: index * _stagger, damping: 80 }}
      >
        {numbersToNice.map((num, idx) => (
          <Text key={idx} style={{ fontSize: fontSize }}>
            {num}
          </Text>
        ))}
      </MotiView>
    </View>
  );
}

// This is the FlatList rendering component
export default function MyList({ data }) {
  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <TickerList number={item.number} fontSize={50} index={index} />
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      initialNumToRender={10}
      maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
      windowSize={5}
      removeClippedSubviews={false} // Prevents removing items from memory
    />
  );
   }

What I’ve Tried:
removeClippedSubviews={false} to keep off-screen items in memory.
Memoizing components using React.memo to prevent unnecessary re-renders.
Adjusting initialNumToRender, maxToRenderPerBatch, and windowSize in the FlatList configuration.
Despite these optimizations, I'm still facing performance issues when animating each list item.
My Question:
How can I use MotiView to animate each item in the FlatList while maintaining smooth performance?
Are there any patterns or best practices to optimize MotiView animations for a large list of items in FlatList?
Should I consider throttling or batching the animations, or are there other methods to optimize the animation performance?
Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!
I want to achieve Smooth run, no long time to render , the app is really stuck trying to render all the animations
